# How can I type in a specific width for my browser? I am using Chrome and the chrome dev-tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to type in a width value for the screen size so I can make proper break points. I often find myself trying to inch one pixel at a time from on size to another. This isn't always successful in Chrome, as I sometimes go by two pixels at a time. Is there a way to make the width a specific typed in width?

I am using Mac OS X. This question has to do with dev tools because I am asking how I can use it to set the browser window width using the keyboard. If I adjust the width between the dev screen and the page with my mouse, a number will appear giving the width and  height of the window. This is useful when using breakpoints to create responsive websites. I would like to know how to do this with my keyboard so I don't have to use my mouse to get point by point precision.

Comment: Which OS is in question? What does setting the browser's Window to a certain width have to do with the google dev tools, or CSS?

Comment: I edited my question because the explanation was too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Chrome Developer Tools, open Console, then select the tab Emulation. Here you'll find "Device" to select from a list of common devices (such as an iPhone; this will also change the user agent as sent to the server), and you'll find "Screen" to set the dimensions manually.

[image]

See also [Mobile emulation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation) in Chrome's help.

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome there's a extension called "Web Developer Tools".
That extension has a feature where you can make the browser resize to a specific HxW. You can even set up your own sizes.

(Not sure if I'm allowed to post links so I will refrain to do so).

Edit:

Thanks Will!

Here's the link to the author of the extension: http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/

Comment: It's encouraged to give links!

Answer (score 1):

There's also another extension called Window Resizer (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh), which does the same as the one mentioned by @Marcelo.  This might be useful to anyone on an older version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach that does not require any plugins.

1. Open the built-in Chrome Developer Tools (`F12` or `Ctrl + Shift + I`)
2. Select the `Console` tab
3. Enter the following to open the a new window with the current url (the next step only works on windows explicitly opened as resizable)

   ```js
   let w = window.open(window.location, "dev resize", "resizable");
   ```

You can then resize the newly opened window either by:

1. Open the Chrome DevTools on the new window and enter

   ```js
   window.resizeTo(window.outerWidth - 1, window.outerHeight);
   ```
2. Return to the original window and enter

   ```js
   w.resizeTo(w.outerWidth - 1, w.outerHeight);
   ```

Repeat the `resizeTo` command as much as you like to decrease width by 1 pixel each time.

Also works in Firefox (and probably Edge, but didn't test)

Tested in:

- Chrome version `111.0.5563.65`
- Firefox version `111.0`
  (I think it's just coincidence that the version numbers match between Firefox and Chrome)